Can boron form quasicrystals like metals?
Quasicrystals are currently only found in metal alloys. These alloys display 5-fold symmetry with icosahedrons as the building blocks. Considering that boron can also form icosahedrons, is it theoretically possible to make a quasicrystals of nonmetal elements?

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on Matter Modeling (or perhaps even Chemistry) SE, but keep in mind the community guidelines/rules regarding cross-posting.

I wonder if you're asking if it's theoretically possible (or there's no theoretical reason it cannot happen) or if they have been found to form in Boron?

By theoretical I mean the formation of such quasicrystals does not violate our knowledge of chemical bonds. For example, you can insert a C≡C moiety in every single C-C bond in diamonds. Such a crystal is perfectly possible in theory even though we have no idea how to synthesize it.

Quasicrystals other then alloys are possible, even organic ones  https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aav0790 https://www.nature.com/articles/nature02368 https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.195502

Googling ‘quasicrystal boron’ yields many possible papers. What have you looked at? And remember that solid state bonding is often unrelated to ‘chemical bonds’.
